# Extract only points inside polygon

Tags: python, pyspark, arcgis, apache-spark-sql, point-in-polygon

I have two CSV file one contain points for polygon around 2000 point (lat, long). another file has more than 1 billion row ( id, lat, long). how to extract only the points intersect(inside) the polygon by pyspark

Comment: I'm currently reading about GeoSpark in hopes of solving a similar problem.

Comment: what is the reference that you reading?

Comment: http://geospark.datasyslab.org/

Answer (score -1):

Insert csv on map and polygons layer for selection.

take **Select by Location** tools and insert to processing.

**Target layer** is point (csv), **Source Layer** is Polygon layer.

**Spatial selection for target layer feature(s)** is **completely contain the source layer feature selected**.

And click apply.

Notes: You must configure porjection same this two layers.